# SQL Update statement updates one row multiple times, but is inconsistent

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

The first question ever on here.

I have an update statement, which seems to have been working perfectly fine, previously.

Out of nowhere, the update statement seems to update a single row multiple times, but not for all rows, if that makes sense?

The statement is run via SQL agent and scheduled every 10 seconds (along with other steps)

Sorry if it's big or messy, I'm self-trained!

The first step, is to insert data into a table that needs to be updated on the main table, using a view.
For the audit trail, I then insert IDs into another table, to track what's being updated.

The problematic part of this statement is the update main table (`DT_V_POTATTENDANCE`).
Below that is an insert into the main table where an ID cannot be found in the view.

The rest of the script again is all part of the audit trail which is how I've found it updating a single row multiple times for whatever reason (but not every time if that makes sense?) and setting the records as updated so they don't keep updating.

Thanks for your help, really appreciate it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * INTO _TEMPTABLEAPPROVEDATTENDANCE
from BE_RPT_PA_ATTENDANCE_TO_UPDATE

SET IDENTITY_INSERT _TEMPTABLEAPPROVEDATTENDANCEUPDATEDSIGNIDS ON
INSERT INTO _TEMPTABLEAPPROVEDATTENDANCEUPDATEDSIGNIDS (SIGNID)
SELECT SIGNID FROM DT_PA_POTATTENDANCE WHERE APPROVED = 1 AND UPDATED IS NULL
SET IDENTITY_INSERT _TEMPTABLEAPPROVEDATTENDANCEUPDATEDSIGNIDS OFF
declare @time datetime
set @time = (select getdate())


UPDATE DT_V_POTATTENDANCE 

SET 
DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.CB_H_MON = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.CB_H_MON + Y.CB_H_MON,
DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.CB_M_MON = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.CB_M_MON + Y.CB_M_MON,
DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.CB_H_TUE = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.CB_H_TUE + Y.CB_H_TUE,
DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.CB_M_TUE = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.CB_M_TUE + Y.CB_M_TUE,
DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.CB_H_WED = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.CB_H_WED + Y.CB_H_WED,
DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.CB_M_WED = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.CB_M_WED + Y.CB_M_WED,
DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.CB_H_THU = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.CB_H_THU + Y.CB_H_THU,
DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.CB_M_THU = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.CB_M_THU + Y.CB_M_THU,
DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.CB_H_FRI = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.CB_H_FRI + Y.CB_H_FRI,
DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.CB_M_FRI = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.CB_M_FRI + Y.CB_M_FRI,

DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.H_H_MON = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.H_H_MON + Y.H_H_MON,
DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.H_M_MON = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.H_M_MON + Y.H_M_MON,
DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.H_H_TUE = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.H_H_TUE + Y.H_H_TUE,
DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.H_M_TUE = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.H_M_TUE + Y.H_M_TUE,
DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.H_H_WED = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.H_H_WED + Y.H_H_WED,
DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.H_M_WED = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.H_M_WED + Y.H_M_WED,
DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.H_H_THU = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.H_H_THU + Y.H_H_THU,
DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.H_M_THU = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.H_M_THU + Y.H_M_THU,
DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.H_H_FRI = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.H_H_FRI + Y.H_H_FRI,
DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.H_M_FRI = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.H_M_FRI + Y.H_M_FRI,

DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.AA_H_MON = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.AA_H_MON + Y.AA_H_MON,
DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.AA_M_MON = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.AA_M_MON + Y.AA_M_MON,
DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.AA_H_TUE = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.AA_H_TUE + Y.AA_H_TUE,
DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.AA_M_TUE = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.AA_M_TUE + Y.AA_M_TUE,
DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.AA_H_WED = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.AA_H_WED + Y.AA_H_WED,
DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.AA_M_WED = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.AA_M_WED + Y.AA_M_WED,
DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.AA_H_THU = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.AA_H_THU + Y.AA_H_THU,
DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.AA_M_THU = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.AA_M_THU + Y.AA_M_THU,
DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.AA_H_FRI = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.AA_H_FRI + Y.AA_H_FRI,
DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.AA_M_FRI = DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.AA_M_FRI + Y.AA_M_FRI


FROM _TEMPTABLEAPPROVEDATTENDANCE Y
WHERE DT_V_POTATTENDANCE.ATTENDANCEWEEKID = Y.ATTENDANCEWEEKID
AND Y.ATTENDANCEWEEKID IS NOT NULL
AND Y.TRAINEEID <> '0683-0001-107827'

INSERT INTO DT_V_POTATTENDANCE
([TRAINEEID]
      ,[POT]
      ,[WEEKSTARTDATE]
      ,[CB_H_MON]
      ,[CB_M_MON]
      ,[CB_H_TUE]
      ,[CB_M_TUE]
      ,[CB_H_WED]
      ,[CB_M_WED]
      ,[CB_H_THU]
      ,[CB_M_THU]
      ,[CB_H_FRI]
      ,[CB_M_FRI]
      ,[H_H_MON]
      ,[H_M_MON]
      ,[H_H_TUE]
      ,[H_M_TUE]
      ,[H_H_WED]
      ,[H_M_WED]
      ,[H_H_THU]
      ,[H_M_THU]
      ,[H_H_FRI]
      ,[H_M_FRI]
      ,[AA_H_MON]
      ,[AA_M_MON]
      ,[AA_H_TUE]
      ,[AA_M_TUE]
      ,[AA_H_WED]
      ,[AA_M_WED]
      ,[AA_H_THU]
      ,[AA_M_THU]
      ,[AA_H_FRI]
      ,[AA_M_FRI])

      SELECT [TRAINEEID]
      ,[POT]
      ,[WEEKSTARTDATE]
      ,[CB_H_MON]
      ,[CB_M_MON]
      ,[CB_H_TUE]
      ,[CB_M_TUE]
      ,[CB_H_WED]
      ,[CB_M_WED]
      ,[CB_H_THU]
      ,[CB_M_THU]
      ,[CB_H_FRI]
      ,[CB_M_FRI]
      ,[H_H_MON]
      ,[H_M_MON]
      ,[H_H_TUE]
      ,[H_M_TUE]
      ,[H_H_WED]
      ,[H_M_WED]
      ,[H_H_THU]
      ,[H_M_THU]
      ,[H_H_FRI]
      ,[H_M_FRI]
      ,[AA_H_MON]
      ,[AA_M_MON]
      ,[AA_H_TUE]
      ,[AA_M_TUE]
      ,[AA_H_WED]
      ,[AA_M_WED]
      ,[AA_H_THU]
      ,[AA_M_THU]
      ,[AA_H_FRI]
      ,[AA_M_FRI] 
      FROM _TEMPTABLEAPPROVEDATTENDANCE
      WHERE ATTENDANCEWEEKID IS NULL
    AND TRAINEEID <> '0683-0001-107827'


      UPDATE DT_PA_POTATTENDANCE

      SET UPDATED = 1 

      FROM DT_PA_POTATTENDANCE

      WHERE APPROVEDTIMESTAMP < @time and
      TRAINEEID <> '0683-0001-107827' AND
APPROVED = 1 AND UPDATED IS NULL AND SIGNID IN (SELECT SIGNID FROM _TEMPTABLEAPPROVEDATTENDANCEUPDATEDSIGNIDS)

INSERT INTO _TEMPTABLEAPPROVEDATTENDANCEUPDATED
([ATTENDANCEWEEKID],[TRAINEEID]
      ,[POT]
      ,[WEEKSTARTDATE]
      ,[CB_H_MON]
      ,[CB_M_MON]
      ,[CB_H_TUE]
      ,[CB_M_TUE]
      ,[CB_H_WED]
      ,[CB_M_WED]
      ,[CB_H_THU]
      ,[CB_M_THU]
      ,[CB_H_FRI]
      ,[CB_M_FRI]
      ,[H_H_MON]
      ,[H_M_MON]
      ,[H_H_TUE]
      ,[H_M_TUE]
      ,[H_H_WED]
      ,[H_M_WED]
      ,[H_H_THU]
      ,[H_M_THU]
      ,[H_H_FRI]
      ,[H_M_FRI]
      ,[AA_H_MON]
      ,[AA_M_MON]
      ,[AA_H_TUE]
      ,[AA_M_TUE]
      ,[AA_H_WED]
      ,[AA_M_WED]
      ,[AA_H_THU]
      ,[AA_M_THU]
      ,[AA_H_FRI]
      ,[AA_M_FRI])

      SELECT [ATTENDANCEWEEKID],[TRAINEEID]
      ,[POT]
      ,[WEEKSTARTDATE]
      ,[CB_H_MON]
      ,[CB_M_MON]
      ,[CB_H_TUE]
      ,[CB_M_TUE]
      ,[CB_H_WED]
      ,[CB_M_WED]
      ,[CB_H_THU]
      ,[CB_M_THU]
      ,[CB_H_FRI]
      ,[CB_M_FRI]
      ,[H_H_MON]
      ,[H_M_MON]
      ,[H_H_TUE]
      ,[H_M_TUE]
      ,[H_H_WED]
      ,[H_M_WED]
      ,[H_H_THU]
      ,[H_M_THU]
      ,[H_H_FRI]
      ,[H_M_FRI]
      ,[AA_H_MON]
      ,[AA_M_MON]
      ,[AA_H_TUE]
      ,[AA_M_TUE]
      ,[AA_H_WED]
      ,[AA_M_WED]
      ,[AA_H_THU]
      ,[AA_M_THU]
      ,[AA_H_FRI]
      ,[AA_M_FRI] 
      FROM _TEMPTABLEAPPROVEDATTENDANCE
      WHERE TRAINEEID <> '0683-0001-107827'

drop table _TEMPTABLEAPPROVEDATTENDANCE
```

Comment: An `UPDATE` statement *can't* affect a single row multiple times. If a row's value is being changed multiple times, then there are multiple `UPDATE`s being run.

Comment: Do you have an update trigger on DT_V_POTATTENDANCE that's retriggering itself?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - no triggers at all unfortunately, and again it doesn't happen on every row that's updated.

Comment: @Larnu that's always been my understanding, but that's the only job running (via sqlagent, occuring once very 10 seconds). From what I've read, an SQLAgent job won't run again if it's already running so it can't be that either. What I don't understand, is why it doesn't multiply every row, only a select few. 

Scenario is college based, learners attend and record their attendance, what the script above is doing is approving and paying that attendance. For one tutor only, and only since last week, it updates the row roughly 16 times!

Comment: Seems like we need a [mre] here, @deanford . Again, I can assure you than a  **single** `UPDATE` won't update a row multiple times. Even if a `JOIN` were to result in many to one relationship, a row would only be affected once. Notice in this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ec4cdf02ad515e8c6fc94ea548a2fde3), for example, that the value of `AnotherInt` is `2` *not* `4`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why it was doing it!

Below part of my script was making it run and run again.

The user in question, we have an MIS that sets the field "Approved" to 1, the script above then updates the master table DT_V_POTATTENDANCE, but it wasn't setting the field "Updated" to 1 because the users time was 3 minutes out!

---

```
  UPDATE DT_PA_POTATTENDANCE

  SET UPDATED = 1 

  FROM DT_PA_POTATTENDANCE

  WHERE APPROVEDTIMESTAMP < @time and
  TRAINEEID <> '0683-0001-107827' AND 
  APPROVED = 1 AND UPDATED IS NULL AND SIGNID IN 
(SELECT SIGNID FROM _TEMPTABLEAPPROVEDATTENDANCEUPDATEDSIGNIDS)
```

---

Thanks for all your help guys, appreciate it!